# Disable drag for only one page in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to disable drag sidemenu of Ionic on only login page so I use this line of code in login controller.

```
$ionicSideMenuDelegate.canDragContent(false);
```

But it disables drag for all pages in my app. How can I fix this?